# How to prevent shifting when adding border on hover? (Transparent border is not a solution)

Tags: html, css

I want to add a border to div on hover, but the div shit slightly when the border is added. It is a well-known problem, and the common solution is to add a transparent border. ([For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19255041/1273587)) However, I have an image with some text in my div and I want the image to take full width of the div. Adding a transparent border will makes the background color shows up and not taking the full width.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container" contenteditable="true">
    <img src="./testing.png">
    some other text
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer-container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000
}
.inner-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background: #FF0000;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.inner-container:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[jsfiddle for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/be7441LL/1/)

The height of the div is variable in actual use as it is to be uploaded by user. I know I can solve the problem with javascript, but is there a way I can make the desired effect with CSS only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply fix this with `outline` property

```
.inner-container:hover {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
 }
```

and if you are using big border
**eg:**
 set `outline:3px; solid blue;` then use `outline-offset:-3px;`

try with demo

https://jsfiddle.net/be7441LL/2/

Comment: Wow, I just done some research and found that it is supported since IE8..... can't believe people still tell other to use border.

Comment: This is doesn't work if you have a div with the border-radius set.
"Outline differs from borders! Unlike border, the outline is drawn outside the element's border, and may overlap other content. Also, the outline is NOT a part of the element's dimensions; the element's total width and height is not affected by the width of the outline."